# Drupal 7 custom module for menu

Tags: 7

I am developing a custom module that will have the functionality to show a particular menu link active on the desired path. For this I have implemented **hook_form_FROM_ID_alter()** hook for **menu_edit_item()**. In the edit form of each menu item there I have provided options similar to block modules page visibility options

- Active on all pages except listed
- Active only on listed pages
- Active depending upon given php code

But I need to match the path listed with any existing path. Do I need to implement other hook or create more functions to implement this or this functionality should be implemented in hook_form_FROM_ID_alter(). I have also created a database table for this that stores

- menu link ID
- Visibility (i.e. flag to the option chosen by the user 0, 1, 2)
- Pages (i.e the paths given by the user in the textarea eg: node/4,
  etc)

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is an existing module which does part of what you want to do. The module is [Menu item visibility](http://drupal.org/project/menu_item_visibility). I recommend looking at how it works and extending it (it says it's extendable) to add the extra pieces you are requesting: visible per page, or visible on PHP code. It probably has hooks you can use to complete your business logic.

In fact, [this issue](http://drupal.org/node/1205566) talks about adding "per page" or "php code" conditions essentially.

Comment: Yeah I have referred that module but this module only provides per role visibility not per page visibility. Just tell me is there any special hook to implement that

Comment: From the 7.x-1.x branch of the module. You would create a hook for `module_invoke_all('menu_item_visibility_load', $visibility, $mlid);` to supply a $visibility array for your FAPI elements to add your custom conditions (page, path, whatever). You would then have to patch function `menu_item_visibility_translated_menu_link_alter()` to use a hook so that your module can write the business logic to enforce your custom $visibility FAPI widget(s).    ... I'm just saying this module does most of what you want, you'd have to help finish that module and learn howto define/implement hooks.